# disable the keyboard FnLock at startup

Tags: linux, keyboard, mapping

The FnLock key is activated at boot on my wired keyboard.

Is there a way to disable it?

Unfortunately, pressing the FnLock key is not visible through showkey nor keytouch.

it is really annoying because all the F1... keyx are remapped to unwanted actions like closing the window.

Comment: According Ignacio, FnLock cannot be disabled but rewriting the firmware. The only workaround I can found is to remap the keyboard to invert the FnLock actions, F2 will act as F2 when fnlock is activated, and will act as "kill window" when it is not activated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FnLock key is under the control of the keyboard firmware and there is no way for software to change this. You would need to rewrite the firmware, but the keyboard manufacturer will not tell you how.